# How to apply postprocessing SSAA to OutlinePass

Tags: three.js

I am trying to use the OutlinePass after SSAA postprocessing but my outline does not show up if I call SSAA after OutlinePass. How can I apply SSAA to my outline? I know FXAA will work but I want to use SSAA.

I have something like:

```
var composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer );

outlinePass = new THREE.OutlinePass( new THREE.Vector2( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight ), scene, camera );
composer.addPass( outlinePass );
outlinePass.visibleEdgeColor.set('#ffffff');
outlinePass.hiddenEdgeColor.set( '#190a05' );
outlinePass.edgeThickness = 5.0;
outlinePass.edgeStrength = 5.0;
outlinePass.edgeGlow = 0.0;
outlinePass.pulsePeriod = 0;
outlinePass.rotate = false;
outlinePass.usePatternTexture = false;  

outlinePass.selectedObjects = [cube];


let ssaaRenderPass = new THREE.SSAARenderPass( scene, camera );
ssaaRenderPass.sampleLevel = 2; 
composer.addPass( ssaaRenderPass );         


copyPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.CopyShader );
copyPass.renderToScreen = true;
composer.addPass( copyPass );
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just applied FXAA to the outline and it looks OK.

So I did SSAA, outlinePass, then FXAA. The FXAA smooth out the shape in the outline.